# How can we calculate statistical uncertainty on number between 0 and 1?

Tags: error-analysis

Lets suppose I have zero events in data. And Monte Carlo predicts 0.5 events. If I take square root of 0.5 to report statistical uncertainty on MC prediction, it comes out to be $\pm0.707$. This means that my MC prediction is bounded by [+1.207, -0.207]. However, I know that MC prediction cannot go below 0.

How can I fix this problem? Your detailed reply is much appreciated in context of experimental high energy physics.

Cheers
Aatif

Comment: Why are you taking the square root of 0.5 as a measure of the statistical uncertainty?

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest way to get this right is to read and understand [Bayes's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). You can't just blindly use formulae designed under certain assumptions when you have low numbers like you do here.

Comment: Also, this isn't a physics question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's a [dedicated SE site for statistics](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) and the question posed here doesn't stand to gain anything by getting a physicist's perspective (I think).

Comment: @DanielSank - But this is pretty basic statistics. I've seen the questions over that the SE statistics website. Most of the questions there are pretty heavy-duty stuff.

Comment: Feldman-Cousins sees a fair amount of use for estimating uncertainties near constraint boundaries in particle physics.

Comment: @DanielSank don't know what you're getting at with Bayes' theorem.

Comment: This should be kept open - it's statistics but it's very relevant to counting experiments in HEP.

Comment: Your mistake is that you assume that the standard deviation, $\sigma = \sqrt{\lambda}$, is such that $\mu \pm \sigma$ contains a probability equivalent to $1\sigma$ (68%), and is a sensible interval. That's only the case for Gaussian distributions.

Comment: I know that if I do it the way I have described above would be wrong. That is way I posted the question. So, using any technique like Feldman-Cousins, is there a way to ensure $1\sigma$ downwards? Question is simple, I admit. A concise answer is what I am looking for. Thanks @Weir for answering.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll take a stab at this. If you're looking for a real number to describe the effective width *w* of the statistical uncertainty in terms of a [0.5-*w*, 0.5+*w*] interval, then it should be obvious by now that no *w* will satisfy your requirements because you don't have a symmetric Gaussian distribution here. Assuming that you're talking about random events populating a bin with an average occupancy of 0.5, you're talking about an "asymmetric" probability distribution bunched up very close to 0.

The probability distribution appropriate for this case is not a Gaussian but a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). Shown below is a Poisson distribution for your case where the average bin count is 0.5 (shown in blue dots). For comparison, the Poisson distribution for the case where the average bin count is 10 is also shown (purple dots). Note that for the case of n=10, the distribution is rather symmetric and taking the square root of the average count of n=10 (sqrt(10)=3.16) actually does give a good measure of the width of the distribution. But for n=0.5, the distribution is not symmetric at all and taking the square root of 0.5 does not give a particularly good intuitive measure of the width of the distribution (although if you're interested in doing formal statistical analyses, sqrt(0.5) actually is the standard deviation of this Poisson distribution).

[image: Poisson Distribution]

According to the Poisson distribution for an average occupancy n=0.5, about 60% of the time there will be no counts, 30% of the time there will be 1 count, about 8% of the time there will be 2 counts, about 1% of the time there will be 3 counts, etc..